# How can one download and run a game uploaded to github?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, github

I have a small game that I created, using c# on visual studio. How can I make one file out of it so people can download it and play on their own computers? (assuming they don't use coding programs (like  Visual Studio) i.e. regular people)

Comment: Sharing a link to your GitHub repo would help with answers to your question.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Publish in Visual Studio (right click project file and click publish). This will package your project and its dependencies into a smaller number of files. There is even an option to create a single file, which may be all you need. If you need an installer, the ClickOnce publish option works great for creating installers.

**Step 2:** Some versions of .NET do not support ClickOnce, and depending on what your needs are you may not want to create a ClickOnce installer. In that case you will have to create an installer yourself. I recommend [Inno Setup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) for creating installers. There are plenty of tutorials on how to use it. Brackeys has a pretty good tutorial on Youtube for Unity projects.